# Make tar stop searching for file after first hit

Tags: bash, tar

I have a big file with a long list of files inside a tarball:

```
subdir1/file1.txt
subdir2/file2.txt
```

I want to extract these files from a tarball by using a `while` loop, like this:

```
while read i
do
tar -xvf tarball.tar.gz $i
done < filelist.txt
```

However, due to the size of the tarball and the filelist, this has a very long runtime because `tar` is searching through the whole tarball even after finding the file in question.

Is there a way to make `tar` stop searching after the first hit? I have tried using the `--occurrence 1` option described [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/getting-gnu-tar-to-stop-when-file-is-found-532603/), but that did not seem to do the trick. I am using `tar` version 1.26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar x` can be given multiple filenames to extract in one run instead of using a loop:

```
readarray -t files <filelist.txt
tar xzvf tarball.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

GNU tar supports a `-T` argument for getting filenames to add or extract directly from another file:

```
tar -xzvf tarball.tar.gz -T filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your version support this option?:

> -q, --fast-read
> (x and t mode only) Extract or list only the first archive entry that matches each pattern or filename operand.  Exit as
> soon as each specified pattern or filename has been
> matched.  By default, the archive is always read to the very end, since there can be multiple entries with the same name and,
> by convention, later entries overwrite earlier
> entries.  This option is provided as a performance optimization.